# Jquery: Switch to tab by click on single button?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have two Tabs, Tab-A and Tab-b, **whenever user click on Tab-A it will show and activate Tab-B but again when user click on Tab-A, while Tab-b is active it has to show Tab-A and it' content**

> Currently when I click on Tab-A it will switch to Tab-B but again when
> I click on Tab-A it has to switch to Tab-A but it's not switching.

```js
// TAB Buttons
const tab1 = document.querySelector('#tab11')
const tab2 = document.querySelector('#tab12')

// TAB Content
const allTabPane = document.querySelectorAll('.tab-pane')

tab1.addEventListener('click', showSecondTab)

function showSecondTab(e) {
  e.preventDefault()
  inactiveAllTabPane()
  setTimeout(function() {
    tab2.click()
  }, 400)

}

function inactiveAllTabPane() {
  for (let i = 0; i < allTabPane.length; i++) {
    const element = allTabPane[i];
    element.classList.remove('active')
  }
}
```

```css
.pg-content p {
  font-family: poppins;
  font-size: 14px;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
}

.acc-head {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  flex-direction: row-reverse;
  align-items: center;
}

.tab-accrd a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #000;
  font-family: poppins;
}

.tab-accrd a i {
  color: #FC453E;
}

.tab-accrd .card {
  background: #eee;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #FC453E;
  border-radius: 0px;
  position: relative;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -ms-flex-direction: column;
  flex-direction: column;
  min-width: 0;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  background-clip: border-box;
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, .125);
}

.tab-accrd .card-header {
  padding: 0.75rem 1.25rem;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .03);
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, .125);
}

.tab-accrd .card-header:first-child {
  border-radius: calc(0.25rem - 1px) calc(0.25rem - 1px) 0 0;
}

.tab-accrd h5 {
  font-size: 20px;
}

.p-0 {
  padding: 0px;
}

.nav-tabs {
  border: none;
}

.ml-1,
.mx-1 {
  margin-left: 0.25rem!important;
}

.accordion-head i {
  float: right;
}

.accordion-head>.collapsed>i:before {
  content: "\f151";
}

html {
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
}

.tab-accrd span {
  font-size: 30px;
  font-weight: 600;
  color: #fc453e;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="col-lg-12 mt-5 tab-accrd">
  <div class="panel with-nav-tabs panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
      <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
        <!-- define id for tabs tab11 and tab12 -->
        <li class="active"><a href="#tab3default" id="tab11" data-toggle="tab">Default 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tab4default" id="tab12" data-toggle="tab">Default 2</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="panel-body">
      <div class="tab-content">
        <div class="tab-pane fade in active" id="tab3default">
          <div class="panel-group" id="faqAccordion">
            <div class="panel panel-default ">
              <div class="panel-heading accordion-toggle question-toggle collapsed" style="padding: 20px;background: #eee;" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#faqAccordion" data-target="#question5">
                <div class="d-flex" style="align-items:center;">
                  <span>1</span>
                  <h5 class="panel-title ml-3">
                    What is Lorem Ipsum?
                  </h5>
                </div>

              </div>
              <div id="question5" class="panel-collapse collapse" style="height: 0px;">
                <div class="panel-body" style="padding: 15px;
                            background: #eee;">
                  <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown

                  </p>

                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="panel panel-default ">
              <div class="panel-heading accordion-toggle collapsed question-toggle" style="padding: 20px;background: #eee;" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#faqAccordion" data-target="#question6">
                <div class="d-flex" style="align-items:center;">
                  <span>2</span>
                  <h5 class="panel-title ml-3">
                    What is Lorem Ipsum?
                  </h5>
                </div>

              </div>
              <div id="question6" class="panel-collapse collapse" style="height: 0px;">
                <div class="panel-body" style="padding: 15px;
                          background: #eee;">
                  <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s
                  </p>

                </div>
              </div>
            </div>

          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="tab-pane fade" id="tab4default">
          <div class="panel-group" id="faqAccordion">
            <div class="panel panel-default ">
              <div class="panel-heading accordion-toggle question-toggle " style="padding: 20px;background: #eee;" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#faqAccordion" data-target="#question9">
                <div class="d-flex" style="align-items:center;">
                  <span>1</span>
                  <h5 class="panel-title ml-3">
                    What is Lorem Ipsum?
                  </h5>
                </div>

              </div>
              <div id="question9" class="panel-collapse" style="height: 0px;">
                <div class="panel-body" style="padding: 15px;
                            background: #eee;">
                  <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the
                  </p>

                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="panel panel-default ">
              <div class="panel-heading accordion-toggle collapsed question-toggle" style="padding: 20px;background: #eee;" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#faqAccordion" data-target="#question1">
                <div class="d-flex" style="align-items:center;">
                  <span>2</span>
                  <h5 class="panel-title ml-3">
                    What is Lorem Ipsum?
                  </h5>
                </div>

              </div>
              <div id="question1" class="panel-collapse" style="height: 0px;">
                <div class="panel-body" style="padding: 15px;
                          background: #eee;">
                  <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type
                  </p>

                </div>
              </div>
            </div>

          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Why would it switch back? The event listener on tab1 triggers a click on tab2 thereby activating it, no matter when you click it.

Comment: @Lalalena it is required because default tab 2 contains heading with description and default tab1 only heading

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check whether a click is needed and if so, perform the click on the correct tab inside a `setTimeout`

```js
// TAB Buttons
const tab1 = document.querySelector('#tab11')
const tab2 = document.querySelector('#tab12')

// TAB Content
const allTabPane = document.querySelectorAll('.tab-pane')

tab1.addEventListener('click', toggleTabs);
tab2.addEventListener('click', toggleTabs);

function clickTab(tab) {
    if (tab.parentNode.classList.contains('active') === false) tab.click();
}

function toggleTabs(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  if (this.parentNode.classList.contains('active')) {
      let toClick = this.parentNode.parentNode.querySelector('li:not(.active) > a');
      setTimeout(function() {
          toClick.click();
      }, 40);
  }
}
```

```css
.pg-content p {
  font-family: poppins;
  font-size: 14px;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
}

.acc-head {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  flex-direction: row-reverse;
  align-items: center;
}

.tab-accrd a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #000;
  font-family: poppins;
}

.tab-accrd a i {
  color: #FC453E;
}

.tab-accrd .card {
  background: #eee;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #FC453E;
  border-radius: 0px;
  position: relative;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -ms-flex-direction: column;
  flex-direction: column;
  min-width: 0;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  background-clip: border-box;
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, .125);
}

.tab-accrd .card-header {
  padding: 0.75rem 1.25rem;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .03);
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, .125);
}

.tab-accrd .card-header:first-child {
  border-radius: calc(0.25rem - 1px) calc(0.25rem - 1px) 0 0;
}

.tab-accrd h5 {
  font-size: 20px;
}

.p-0 {
  padding: 0px;
}

.nav-tabs {
  border: none;
}

.ml-1,
.mx-1 {
  margin-left: 0.25rem!important;
}

.accordion-head i {
  float: right;
}

.accordion-head>.collapsed>i:before {
  content: "\f151";
}

html {
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
}

.tab-accrd span {
  font-size: 30px;
  font-weight: 600;
  color: #fc453e;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="col-lg-12 mt-5 tab-accrd">
  <div class="panel with-nav-tabs panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
      <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
        <!-- define id for tabs tab11 and tab12 -->
        <li class="active"><a href="#tab3default" id="tab11" data-toggle="tab">Default 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tab4default" id="tab12" data-toggle="tab">Default 2</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="panel-body">
      <div class="tab-content">
        <div class="tab-pane fade in active" id="tab3default">
          <div class="panel-group" id="faqAccordion">
            <div class="panel panel-default " onclick="tab1.click()">
              <div class="panel-heading accordion-toggle question-toggle collapsed" style="padding: 20px;background: #eee;" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#faqAccordion" data-target="#question5">
                <div class="d-flex" style="align-items:center;">
                  <span>1</span>
                  <h5 class="panel-title ml-3">
                    What is Lorem Ipsum?
                  </h5>
                </div>

              </div>
              <div id="question5" class="panel-collapse collapse" style="height: 0px;">
                <div class="panel-body" style="padding: 15px;
                            background: #eee;">
                  <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown

                  </p>

                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="panel panel-default " onclick="tab2.click()">
              <div class="panel-heading accordion-toggle collapsed question-toggle" style="padding: 20px;background: #eee;" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#faqAccordion" data-target="#question6">
                <div class="d-flex" style="align-items:center;">
                  <span>2</span>
                  <h5 class="panel-title ml-3">
                    What is Lorem Ipsum?
                  </h5>
                </div>

              </div>
              <div id="question6" class="panel-collapse collapse" style="height: 0px;">
                <div class="panel-body" style="padding: 15px;
                          background: #eee;">
                  <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s
                  </p>

                </div>
              </div>
            </div>

          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="tab-pane fade" id="tab4default">
          <div class="panel-group" id="faqAccordion">
            <div class="panel panel-default " onclick="tab1.click()">
              <div class="panel-heading accordion-toggle question-toggle " style="padding: 20px;background: #eee;" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#faqAccordion" data-target="#question9">
                <div class="d-flex" style="align-items:center;">
                  <span>1</span>
                  <h5 class="panel-title ml-3">
                    What is Lorem Ipsum?
                  </h5>
                </div>

              </div>
              <div id="question9" class="panel-collapse" style="height: 0px;">
                <div class="panel-body" style="padding: 15px;
                            background: #eee;">
                  <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the
                  </p>

                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="panel panel-default " onclick="tab2.click()">
              <div class="panel-heading accordion-toggle collapsed question-toggle" style="padding: 20px;background: #eee;" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#faqAccordion" data-target="#question1">
                <div class="d-flex" style="align-items:center;">
                  <span>2</span>
                  <h5 class="panel-title ml-3">
                    What is Lorem Ipsum?
                  </h5>
                </div>

              </div>
              <div id="question1" class="panel-collapse" style="height: 0px;">
                <div class="panel-body" style="padding: 15px;
                          background: #eee;">
                  <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type
                  </p>

                </div>
              </div>
            </div>

          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Thank you tonnes a time! this works like a charm.... :) also `How can it work with accordion  like if I click on any accordion of - default 1 it will also needs redirect only to Default2`  **like when click on 1 rather than opening it will redirect to default 2 tab content**

Comment: @archana happy to help. If this answer solved your question, then you may accept it as the correct answer. As about your second question in the comment, at this point it does not seem to be clear to me. Maybe you could ask a separate question here on SO and share its link with me here in the comment section. In the other question I recommend the creation of another code snippet where you have and example with an accordion.

Comment: I am saying `whenever user clicked on default1 accordion elements like 1,2` as seen in [img](https://imgur.com/a/Npj7V1Z) it should also redirec to deault tab2

Comment: @archana I see. Let me take a look.

Comment: @archana I have edited my answer to solve that. The solution was to add an `onclick` to the spans and implement a function for it to make sure that it only switches if the accordion corresponds to an inactive tab.

Comment: it only works when I clicked on Default1 tab's span-1 and span-1 number but it has to be work on all the areas of 1 and 2 number accordions in Default1 Tab!!

Comment: @archana if you are on Default1 and you click on the "1" accordion, do you want to switch to Default2? I assumed a different intention, but will edit my answer so it will switch the tab if you click any accordion.

Comment: @archana you can test it now. Is it fulfilling your requirements in the current version?

Comment: now I am trying when user click on any area not only on span only see [image](https://imgur.com/a/pmeQl0K), when user click on any rather of 1,2 accordion it should redirect to default to rather than opening it

Comment: @archana I do not understand your last statement, but will make some further adjustments to my answer with the hope that I guess your requirement correctly.

Comment: @archana edited my answer. If it is still not fulfilling the requirements, then I will need a precise specification of what your requirements are, because so far I have tried to guess what you wanted to do with the accordions and my guesses did not match it. So, please explain the exact needs you have.